# WatchOS: which icon is used in the MyWatch App

Tags: ios, iphone, watchos-2

I'm currently building a WatchOS2 app.

Everything works fine, except that when my app is listed in the MyWatch app on my iPhone, it is displayed without the icon.

I googled a lot, but haven't found any hints on the required icon (size, name, location, ...), or hints on which icon will be used from the MyWatch app.

Thanks for any hints on this.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are putting your icons ".png" files into the asset catalog in the **main watch app folder**, not the app "extension" folder. Next, note that the files under "Apple Watch Companion Settings" will be the ones that show up in the Apple Watch app on the paired iOS device. The sizes should be **58px** for the 2x and **87px** for the 3x. To get the files in the proper location, all you need to do is drag and drop them into your "Assets.xcassets" folder for the Apple Watch app.

As far as getting it to show up on the iOS simulator, I cannot get it to show up either. When I run the same apps on the actual watch and phone though, the icons show up just fine inside of the Apple Watch app on my iPhone.

For more information on Apple Watch icons, check out the [human interface guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked that everything is like you told me (I think the 2x companion icon size should be 58px), but MyWatch still doesn't display my icons... Then I created a new project from scratch, set all the required icons and it works (at least after a few deployments of the app to my iPhone, but still no icons in the simulator). Strange thing here: after replacing all my icons in my app, the MyWatch still shows the initially used icon, even after removing/reinstalling the app and verifying that the initially used icon isn't contained in the project any more...

Comment: Sorry about that, it is 58px. Yeah I can't get the one in the simulator to work either... It seems that the whole icon setup for the watch is quite temperamental. Best of luck getting it all sorted out

Comment: I'm having this too. All the correct icons are in the xcassets in the watch app. I've tried creating new projects and they still don't appear. One thing I noticed is that when I select the project, select the watch app, and under general, both the phone app's icon set and the watch apps's icon set were named "AppIcon". Somehow it was on the set for the phone app, but when I tried to change it to the one for the watch app, it would always go back to being the one for the phone app. So I changed the name to "AppIcon-Watch". This let me select it, but it still doesn't appear on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

Use this website for generating app icons for all platforms:-

http://makeappicon.com

Upload a 1024*1024 pixel app icon and this website will take care of the rest